# Hadoop dfs java client not working

Tags: hadoop

I have just started learning hadoop. below mentioned is my java code to connect to hadoop hdfs.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs.open(new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310"))));
        String line = null;
        line = reader.readLine();
        while(line!=null){
            System.out.println(line);
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        fs.close();
```

i am getting error stating that hdfs://localhost:54310 is not a valid file name.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `hdfs://localhost:54310` is a valid [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax) but not a valid file name.

You should specify the path part of the URI:

```
new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/path/to/your/file.txt")
```